# How use correctly the NavController component

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I need do this:

```
  async doLogin(user: User) {
    try {
      const result = await this.AngularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      if (result) {
        this.AngularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
          if (user) {
            var ref = firebase.database().ref(`profile/${user.uid}`);
            ref.once("value")
              .then(function(snapshot) {
                var key = snapshot.key;
                if (user.uid === key) {
                  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
                }
                else {
                  this.navCtrl.setRoot(ProfilePage);
                }
              });
          }
        });
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: this.loginErrorString,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'top'
      });
      toast.present();
    }
  }
```

But i got this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined`

I don't know why it does it but i think that the method  doLogin can't read the module navCtrl. The navCtrl method was add to construct obviously.

Best Regards friends

Comment: Change `.then(function(snapshot) {` to an arrow function. `function` keyword creates a new `this` context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use arrow functions `(snapshot) => {...}` instead of regular `function(snapshot) {...}`. In your case you're using `this` keyword, so there are many issues with old functions, which were solved in new ES6 arrow functions!

For more info about arrow functions and `this`: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Comment: Thanks you! I study the arrow functions and this works without problems